# Formula Field throwing error while creating field

Tags: formula-field, error

Trying this

**Owner:User.Profile.Name**

I am creating formula field to show Owner profile (which type of) but its given error that **You don't need to specify an object type for the Owner field. Remove User from your formula.**

Comment: Which object are you creating this field? When I created the field, I don't see such error!

Comment: on Contact object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In contact object this will be **Owner.Profile.Name** . What you tried works in Lead or Case object, because the owner field is hybrid - can refer to user or Queue.

Try this and let me know if you are still getting any error.

Comment: I'm trying to do the same to use formula field to get out Owner.Manager.Name but getting same error as OP. Any clues bro?